# Two Websites with the same administration Panel In Wordpress

Tags: multisite

Requirement is to create two websites with wordpress :

- The official Website for Desktop . (www.mydomain.com)
- The Mobile Version . (m.mydomain.com)

What I want is to create another Website for the mobile version but with the same content or database (Posts - Categories - Pages - administration Panel .. ) .

So, What to do ?

Comment: Is a single responsive site not an option?

Comment: We help people with their code here.  What have you tried so far? You might find it helpful to read [ask]

Answer (score 1):

Ideally for this you have to create a network or multi-site installation. Using multi-site you can create as many sites as you want and you can login/manage those through single admin panel.

Reference: https://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network

Hope this is what your were looking for.

Comment: Thanks. I created the network .. but how to make my websites similar .. i mean same content categories and  posts

Comment: Hey, There are plugins available for that, try this one https://wordpress.org/plugins/multisite-clone-duplicator/